# Выпадающий список на CSS3 c помощью translateY

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть

```
<div class='open_some_block'>
  Открить
  <ul>
    <li>один</li>
    <li>два</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>Что то еще</div>
```

При нажатии на `open_some_block` список должен открываться. Как сделать это с помощью `transform: translateY` так, чтобы этот выпадающий список двинул второй блок в низ?

PS Знаю как это сделать с помощью `heigth`, вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/50gsLtL2/12/. Но мне этот вариант не подходит

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/bztbby67/

Comment: К сожалению, `transform` не изменяет разметку, поэтому сдвинуть им другие элементы не получится.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/p6gf6jsj/

Comment: Можете посмотреть [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503811/Не-работает--transition/505984#505984) мой ответ — может какие-нибудь идеи придут. P. S. Ну и сам там вопрос изучите, чтобы понять, что мы пытались сделать.

Comment: Не сочтите за рекламу, но может быть поможет.  На ютубе видел пример с таким раздвигающимся списком, в поиске введи Уроки по CSS/CSS3. Часть 19. Анимации (animation) это вроде то что тебе нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Как на счет такого варианта?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#opentext').click(function() {
    $('#text').slideToggle()
  });
});
```

```css
#text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="opentext">Показать текст полностью</div>
<div id="text">
  <p>Текст текст текст текст</p>
  <p>Текст текст текст текст</p>
  <p>Текст текст текст текст</p>
  <p>Текст текст текст текст</p>
</div>
<div>второй блок</div>
```

Comment: Просили на css же. Со скриптом и так везде полно примеров.