# Не работает transition

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть такая разметка

```js
$('a.plus').click(function() {

  $(this).next().toggleClass("open");
  return false;

});
```

```css
.more {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10px;
  transition: .3s;
}
.open {
  height: auto;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp_note"><a class="plus">ссылка</a>
  <div class="more">
    <div class="note">
      <p>Федеральный закон от 02.05.2015 N 122-ФЗ</p>
      <p>"О внесении изменений в Трудовой кодекс Российской Федерации и статьи 11 и 73 Федерального закона "Об образовании в Российской Федерации"</p>
      <p>Начало действия документа - 01.07.2016</p>
      <p>Приказом Минтруда России от 19 октября 2015 г. N 728н утвержден профессиональный стандарт "Аудитор". Этот документ представляет собой характеристику квалификации, необходимой работнику для осуществления аудиторской деятельности и оказания прочих
        связанных с ней услуг.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Дело в том,что при нажатии на ссылку открывается блок `more` но не плавно,если же тут  `.open {height:auto;transition:.3s;}` установить фиксированную высоту,то будет все плавно,как быть, мне необходимо именно с `height:auto` работать

https://jsfiddle.net/e2t1kcro/

Comment: ссылка не ведет на код, и обычный workaround использовать min-height или max-height

Comment: Все теперь ведет

Comment: _мне необходимо именно с height:auto работать_ - transition не работает `height:auto`. Можете использовать jQuery и slideToggle

Comment: slideToggle работает с display none,Это не очень хорошо индексируется

Comment: jQuery.animate и height

Comment: А с `height:auto;` будет работать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37096/discussion-between-grundy-and-zkolya).

Comment: Как вам такой варинат https://jsfiddle.net/fabric/gs118p1d/ ?

Comment: @IgorTkachuk,очень круто, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно использовать свойство `transform` и его функцию `scaleY()`; однако при этом есть один нюанс, который заключается в том, что нижеследующий контент в начале анимации сразу же будет занимать конечное положение:

```js
var dashboard = document.body.firstElementChild;


dashboard.addEventListener( 'click', function () {

  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('open');

} );
```

```css
.details {
  height: 0;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scaleY( 0 );
}

.open {
  height: auto;
  transform: scaleY( 1 );
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div>Click me!</div>
<div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div>--------------------------------------------------</div>
```

Мой листинг: https://jsfiddle.net/kfbfe52x/ .

Ваш листинг: https://jsfiddle.net/e2t1kcro/2/ .

---

Для какого-нибудь слайдера или меню, которые имеют абсолютное позиционирование, вполне годный вариант:

> https://jsfiddle.net/kfbfe52x/1/